# Rendering an array of ember components that accept different parameters

Tags: ember.js

At the end of some processing I want to have an array of components that I want to render to the screen.

So I imagine I could do something like this:

```
const someComponent = SomeComponent.create({
 param1: 'something',
 param2: 'something else'
});
this.get('myComponents').pushObject(someComponent);
```

And then

{{#each myComponents as |component|}}
   //render these somehow
{{/each}}

I can't use the `component` helper because I have a number of different components and they all accept different parameters.

Comment: is it possible to toss all the parameters into an attrs object, and then use the component helper?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps at the end of your processing you could have an array of data instead of an array of components. The data could include some way for you to decide which component should be used for that data in the template, plus the parameteres to be used. Then, assuming you have a sane number of different possible components, you could conditionally render them in your template depending on the type.

```
{{#each myComponentData as |data|}}
    {{#if data.isDate}}
        {{date-picker default=data.defaultDate}}
    {{/if}}
    {{#if data.isSomeOtherType}}
        {{component-for-other-type param1=data.relevantParameter}}
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I am doing currently - I was wondering if there is a better way because the list is getting very big.